# Chrome Dev Tools not recognizing a function under Watches

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

I am coming across a very strange problem with Chrome Dev tools. My browser version is 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit), which is the latest version.

I am debugging a script that contains a function `validatePositiveIntegerValue` but it's saying under watch `<not available>` for a watch expression using this function. But, if I use `validateIntegerValue("23.34")` then it recognizes the function and shows a value. So I am very confused why some methods are being recognized and some are not, even when they are defined within the same block.

I did try to render the page in an incognito window and also pressed Ctrl + Shift + R to refresh scripts, but it did nothing.

**Question**

Why is the function `validatePositiveIntegerValue` that exists not being recognized by a watch expression, but `validatePositiveValue` that is defined within the same block is being recognized by a watch expression?

**Script Window in Chrome Dev Tools**
[image: Chrom Dev Tools Script Window]

**Watch Expression in Chrome Dev Tools**

[[image: Chrome Dev Tools Watch Expression Problem[3]]

**HOW TO REPRODUCE this issue**

The closest I could get to reproducing this issue is by running the below html file in Chrome. Then, when I click on either of the 2 buttons, and break within `doSomething` method within `myValidation`, I cannot evaluate this watch expression `validatePositiveIntegerValue("23.sd")`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Chrome Dev Tools Issue</title>
<script>
function doSomething1() {
  alert("hi 1");
  var isvalid =rpv.validateIntegerValue("dsdsd");
}

function doSomething2() {
  alert("hi 2");
   var isvalid = rpv.validateIntegerValue("dsdsd");
}


function myValidation() {
  var eo = {};

  eo.validateIntegerValue = function(integerValue) {
    doSomething();
    if (!integerValue) {
      return false;
    }
    if (isNaN(integerValue) === true) {
      return false;
    }
    return parseInt(integerValue).toString() === $.trim(integerValue.toString());
  }
   function validatePositiveIntegerValue(integerValue) {
    if (!integerValue) {
      return false;
    };
    if (isNaN(integerValue) === true) {
      return false;
    }
    return parseInt(integerValue).toString() === $.trim(integerValue.toString()) && parseInt(integerValue) >= 0;
  }
  function doSomething() {
     var x = 20;
   }

  function validateNegativeIntegerValue(integerValue) {
    if (!integerValue) {
      return false;
    };
    if (isNaN(integerValue) === true) {
      return false;
    }
    return parseInt(integerValue).toString() === $.trim(integerValue.toString()) && parseInt(integerValue) < 0;
  }

  function validatePositiveOrZeroIntegerValue(integerValue) {
    if (!integerValue) {
      return false;
    };
    if (isNaN(integerValue) === true) {
      return false;
    }
    return parseInt(integerValue).toString() === $.trim(integerValue.toString()) && parseInt(integerValue) > 0;
  }

  return eo;

}

var rpv = myValidation();
</script>
</head>
<body>
Chrome Dev Tools Issue with Watch Expression not recognising a function
<button id="btn1" onclick="doSomething1();return false;">Call doSomething1 method</button>
<button id="btn1" onclick="doSomething2();return false;">Call doSomething2 method</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

I have created a Chrome bug at following url: [Chrome Bug Item](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=708459#)

Comment: Looks like a bug. Consider reporting on https://crbug.com if it hasn't been done already.

Comment: wOxxOm, Thanks for that. Do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co including `javascript`?

Comment: @guest271314, I will do that when I am back after work.

Comment: This seems to be a chrome bug. Try downgrading chrome to 56.0, and it should work as expected.

Comment: I've seen this before-- it's a weird one-- seems to be some optimization under the hood that prevents variables/functions in higher scopes from being available in the dev tools in lower scopes _unless they are explicitly referred to_.  If you were to put a console log in your `validatePositiveValue` of `console.log(validatePositiveValue)` I bet that when you paused inside `validatePositiveValue` your watcher would then show a value.

Comment: @aried, yes, when I put a call to the function within the script file where I am stopping to watch for expressions, then the call is successful in script and is also available in watch expression.

Comment: @Sunil -- yeah, it doesn't even need to be a call-- a console log or any other reference will cause it to be available.  Probably Chrome team trying to save some RAM...

Comment: @guest271314, I don't think it might be possible to create a sample for this since if I define a new script file then all functions are recognized, but if I add some new functions and reload the same page then only this issue shows up.

Comment: @guest271314, I added an update on how to reproduce this issue. Please have a look. I could not do this in plnkr.co.

Comment: I have created a bug at Chrome site for this. You can see it at: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=708459#